# How to get value of 2 dropdown list who's value coming from javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have 2 dropdownlist in jsp as 'speciality' and 'super_speciality'[clicking on speciality related superspeciality populates] and **their values coming from javascript file** 'specialities.js', ***how to get values of these 2 dropdownlist in Servlet or JSP ???***

my

```js
// specialities.js file

// speciaities
var spl_arr = new Array("Dentist","Gynecologist/obstetrician","Dermatologist/cosmetologist",
        "Pediatrician","General Physician","Ayurveda","Cardiologist",
        "Orthopedist","Ear-nose-throat (ent)","Homeopath");

//  Super Specialities
var SupSpl_arr = new Array();

SupSpl_arr[0]="";
SupSpl_arr[1]="General Dentists|Oral Pathologists|Periodontists|Orthodontists|Cosmetic Dentists|";
SupSpl_arr[2]="Maternal-fetal medicine|Family planning|Reproductive endocrinology and infertility|Female pelvic medicine and reconstructive surgery|Menopausal and geriatric |";
SupSpl_arr[3]="Cosmecaregiver|Desairologist|Hair colorist|Esthecaregiver|";
SupSpl_arr[4]="Fictional pediatricians‎|Neonatologists‎|Pediatric ophthalmologists‎|Pediatric organizations|Women pediatricians|";
SupSpl_arr[5]="Auto-isopathy|Classical homeopathy|Clinical homeopathy|Homotoxicology|Pluralistic homeopathy|";
SupSpl_arr[6]="Multiple Sclerosis (MS)|Parkinson’s disease (PD)|Ankylosing Spondylities (AS)|Rheumatoid arthritis (RA)|Paralysis|";
SupSpl_arr[7]="Cardiac electrophysiology|Echocardiography|Interventional cardiolog|Nuclear cardiology|Pediatric cardiology|";
SupSpl_arr[8]="Hand and Plastic Surgery|Pediatric Orthopaedics|Back and spine conditions|Trauma|";
SupSpl_arr[9]="OTOLOGY-NEUROTOLOGY (EAR)|RHINOLOGY (NOSE)|LARYNGOLOGY (THROAT)|HEAD/NECK/THYROID|ALLERGY|GENERAL OTOLARYNGOLOGY|PEDIATRIC OTOLARYNGOLOGY (CHILDREN)|";
SupSpl_arr[10]="Allergy and Immunology|Anaesthesiology|Endocrinology|Gastroenterology|";



function populateSuperSpecialities( specialityElementId, superSpecialityElementId ){
 
 var selectedSpecialityIndex = document.getElementById( specialityElementId ).selectedIndex;

 var superSpecialityElement = document.getElementById( superSpecialityElementId );
 
 superSpecialityElement.length=0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
 superSpecialityElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Super Speciality','');
 superSpecialityElement.selectedIndex = 0;
 
 var super_arr = SupSpl_arr[selectedSpecialityIndex].split("|");
 
 for (var i=0; i<super_arr.length; i++) {
  superSpecialityElement.options[superSpecialityElement.length] = new Option(super_arr[i],super_arr[i]);
 }
}

function populateSpecialities(specialityElementId, superSpecialityElementId){
 // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
 var specialityElement = document.getElementById(specialityElementId);
 specialityElement.length=0;
 specialityElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Speciality','-1');
 specialityElement.selectedIndex = 0;
 for (var i=0; i<spl_arr.length; i++) {
  specialityElement.options[specialityElement.length] = new Option(spl_arr[i],spl_arr[i]);
 }

 // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

 if( superSpecialityElementId ){
  specialityElement.onchange = function(){
   populateSuperSpecialities( specialityElementId, superSpecialityElementId );
  };
 }
}
```

```html
// inside my jsp  
<script type= "text/javascript" src = "js/specialities.js"></script>


Select Speciality: <select id="speciality" name="speciality">
   <script language="javascript">
    populateSpecialities("speciality", "super_speciality");
   </script>
  </select>
 Select Super-Speciality: <select id="super_speciality" name="super_speciality"  style="width: 198px">
  <script language="javascript">
     populateSuperSpecialities("speciality", "super_speciality");     
  </script>  
 </select>
```

Comment: Are you submitting the form to servlet ? Where is servlet code ? Add that in your question

Comment: Where is your form in jsp ?

Answer (score 0):

In Jsp and Servlet you can get the values of the elements using `request` object.

To get the value of any element use the method called `getParameter` of request object. Below code in servlet and jsp will give you the value.

```
String value = request.getParameter("super_speciality");
```

Similarly, You can get the value of other parameter as well.